# Embedded Raven DataDirectory on my Dropbox not working 100%?

Tags: c#, ravendb

I have my project files on my Dropbox folder so I can play around with my files at the office as well.

My project contains an `EmbeddableDocumentStore` with `UseEmbeddedHttpServer` set to `true`.

```
const int ravenPort = 8181;
NonAdminHttp.EnsureCanListenToWhenInNonAdminContext(ravenPort);
var ds = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { 
    DataDirectory = "Data", 
    UseEmbeddedHttpServer = true, 
    Configuration = { Port = ravenPort } 
};
```

Now, this day when I started my project on my office pc I saw this message: `Could not open transactional storage: D:\Dropbox\...\Data`

Since it's early in my development stage I deleted the data folder on my Dropbox and the project started flawlessly. Now I'm back at home I ran into the same issue! I don't want to end up deleting this folder every time of course.

Can't I store my development data on my Dropbox? Should I bypass something to get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set a data directory to a physical disk volume on your local computer.  You will not be able to use any sort of mapped drive, network share, UNC path, dropbox or skydrive as a data directory.  Just because you have a drive letter does not mean you have a physical disk.

The only types of non-physical storage that even make sense is a LUN attached from a SAN over iSCSI or FibreChannel, or an attached VHD in a virtualized or cloud environment.  They will all present as physical disks to the OS.

This would be the case for just about ANY data access environment. Try it with SQL Server if you don't believe me.  In RavenDB's case, it is using ESENT as its data store, which requires direct access to the filesystem.

**Update**

To clarify, even if you are storing on a physical disk, you can't rely on any type of synchronization technology like DropBox or SkyDrive.  Why?  Because they will be taking a shared read lock on the files to watch for changes.  Technologies like ESENT (which RavenDB is based upon) require an *exclusive lock* to the file.

Other technologies like SQL Server and Windows Virtual Machine also take exclusive locks on their data stores.  Why?  Because they are constantly reading and writing bits of data in a random-access manner to the file.  Would you really want DropBox to be trying to perform an sync operation for every bit of data change?  It would be very inefficient and problematic.

Applications that use shared locks don't have this problem.  For example, when you work on an MS Word document, it is all being done in memory. When you save the file, DropBox can read the entire file and sync it to the cloud.  It can optimize by sending only the bits that have changed, but it still needs to be able to read the file to do so.

So if DropBox has a shared read lock on the ESENT file, then when RavenDB tries to open it exclusively, it gets an error and raises the exception you are seeing.

Comment: Isn't DropBox just a folder on the local drive that is synchronised lazily? As far as RavenDB is concerned I think it should be just a folder on the local drive...

Comment: Yes, but ESENT requires an *exclusive lock* on the file while it is open.  It is working in this file constantly, just like SQL .mdf/.ldf files, or a Virtual Machine's .vhd file would.  DropBox/SkyDrive needs  to get out of the way so the lock can be obtained.  Sure, once the lock was released - it could sync up.  But I don't think it's smart enough to do that.  It's expecting you're working with documents, images, and other files that can use *shared locks*.

Comment: I am not debugging on both machines at the same time, so the RavenDB engine keeps it locked even if it doesn't run anymore?

Comment: No, DropBox does though.  Raven can't open its exclusive lock because there's already a shared read lock open by DropBox.  If you stop DropBox (if it has a mechanism for doing so), Raven should be ok.  Then you can start DropBox after shutting Raven down to sync your changes.